# Why do I get an error in PyCharm when trying to add the opencv module despite being already installed

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, opencv

When trying to install the opencv-python package I get the following error

`Error occurred when installing package 'opencv-python'`.

I already did the `pip install opencv-python` in the commmand prompt. When I try to do it again I get `'Requirement already satisfied'`. And yet I cannot add it in PyCharm.. any ideas?

Comment: If you go to File\Settings\Project<:name>\Project Interpreter, do you see `opencv-python` in the list of packages?

Comment: I do, but when I select it and press 'Install package' I get the error

Comment: Ok. How are you trying to add it to Pycharm? Is there any code you can add to see how you are trying to use this package?

Comment: "import cv2"
but I get the same error if I go to File\Settings\Project<:name>\Project Interpreter and try to install the cv2 package

Comment: Does your file interpreter match your project interpreter? Check the file interpreter by clicking the file name(upper right side of the PyCharm screen) then "Edit Configurations...". and check the Python Interpreter there matches the Interpreter in your Settings\Project\Project Interpreter.**Ensure the full interpreter path is the same.**

Comment: Try `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Answer (score 0):

When you installed opencv you installed it in  a certain environment. Make sure that you are using that same environment in pycharm. Go to File-Settings-Project Name-Project Interpreter. Look at what interpreter it displays and if it is not in the same environment
in which you installed opencv, then click on the small down arrow and a list of interpreters will drop down. Select the one for the environment in which you installed opencv.